# Is there any way to stop and then start a discord.py bot without having to restart the whole py file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

According to discord.py's discord server as well as their docs you'd need to restart the whole py file after using 'bot.close()' since it disconnects from their api. Unfortunately I'm trying to create a launcher and it wouldn't really be ideal to restart the whole launcher to restart the bot, does anyone know any 'hacky' ways of starting up a discord.py bot after using 'bot.close()'? it doesn't have to be pretty, just needs to remotely work. Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
    @asyncSlot()
    async def on_btnStartBot_clicked(self):
        self.pushButton_startBot.setEnabled(False)
        if self.isBotRunning == False:
            self.statusbar.showMessage("Starting Bot...")
            try:
                if isinstance(cfg["bot"]["token"], str) and cfg["bot"]["token"] != "":
                    await bot.start(cfg["bot"]["token"])
                elif isinstance(cfg["bot"]["token"], list) and not all(token == "" for token in cfg["bot"]["token"]):
                    def first_token():
                        for t in cfg["bot"]["token"]:
                            if t != "":
                                return t
                    await bot.start(first_token())
                else:
                    terminal.log("CRITICAL", f"No token was provided in '{utils.config.CONFIG_PATH}'")
            except Exception as e:
                self.statusbar.showMessage(str(e))
        else:
            self.statusbar.showMessage("Stopping Bot...")
            await bot.close()
            self.plainTextEdit_botTerminal.clear()
            while not bot.is_closed():
                print('Not Yet Closed')
            if bot.is_closed():
                print("Closed")
                self.statusbar.showMessage("Bot Has Been Stopped...")
                self.pushButton_startBot.setText("Start Bot")
                self.isBotRunning = False
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                self.pushButton_startBot.setEnabled(True)
```

Comment: Please don’t paste screenshots of code. Add the code directly instead (ideally a minimal example).

Comment: create another script that runs the launcher and then calls the script that starts the bot, this can run independently and end after bot.close() is called. This can then be restarted by just calling the script again from the launcher script

Comment: Add all functionality to cogs, then load and unload the cogs to restart the bot without closing it.

Comment: So you want to make a command who restart the bot?

Comment: @Ceres the launcher is intended to be universal. It wouldn't appeal to bot operators if it only restarted cogs :/

Comment: @SeanPowell I'll give that a shot and see how it goes. Will update when I do

Comment: Use cogs, you can load/unload those. Not sure why you would like to stop/start the bot itself

Comment: @SeanPowell can you send an answer along the lines of your comment so I can accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be best to create a second script that loops forever, then you can call the script to start the bot, this bot script can then end when `bot.close()` is called. Then when the bot needs to be started again you can call the bot script again. This would allow you to easily restart the bot without having to restart the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write your BOT in a own class or in a function.
I`m not too sure that could work but you can try it.

Comment: bot is written as its own class, issue is the api call. Once you call close, it refuses to connect again :/

Comment: Ok then you have to make 2 Scripts wich call each other so you have a infinite loop. Or i don`t know the answer.